# Getting script to recognise text and arrange in correct column based on cell text

Tags: vba, sorting

```html
'Text to columns, seperate into columns
wsx1.Columns(2).TextToColumns , _
Destination:=wsx1.Range("B1"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
Other:=True, _
OtherChar:="|", _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=False
'remove unwanted information & shift cells accross
For Each cell In wsx1.Range("A1:AD50000")
    If cell.Value = "Pre-trigger Time: 20[s]" Then
        cell.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
    End If
 Next cell
 
 For Each cell In wsx1.Range("A1:AD50000")
    If cell.Value = "§@" Then
        cell.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
    End If
 Next cell
'Now, copy what you want from x:
lRows = wsx1.Cells(wsx1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lCols = wsx1.Cells(1, wsx1.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
Set rng3 = wsx1.Range(wsx1.Cells(1, 1), wsx1.Cells(lRows, lCols))
'Identify next empty range in final sheet
sizex = rng3.Columns.Count
sizey = rng3.Rows.Count
lRows2 = wsy1.Cells(wsy1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
DRows = sizey + lRows2
DCols = sizex
Set rng4 = wsy1.Range(wsy1.Cells(lRows2 + 1, 1), wsy1.Cells(DRows, DCols))
rng4.Value = rng3.Value
wsy1.Columns("A:Q").AutoFit
'Close x:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
x.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I am extracting information from a CSV file, First I am separating the string using text to columns and then transferring the data to the correct workbook.
 The issue I m having is trying to find a way to recognise the text content for e.g. Date should go in column 2, time in column 3, etc...

```html
Samatar1 Date:01/01/15 Time: 12:46 Record Duration: 25 s Data: exc Experiment: S2 Workspace : mina 

The above format is how the text is shown in the table
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Sub move_Data()
Dim iL As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, pasterng As Range, lRow As Long, lRows As Long, str As String, var As Range, var1 As Range, var2 As Range, var3 As Range, var4 As Range, var5 As Range, var6 As Range, titlerow As Long

Set ws1 = Sheet1
Set ws2 = Sheet2

iL = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To iL

Set Title1 = ws1.Cells(i, 1)

titlerow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
titlerows = titlerow + 1

Set Title2 = ws2.Cells(titlerows, 1)

Title2.Value = Title1.Value

Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Cells(i, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Columns)
Set var = rng1.Find("Date: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 2)
pasterng.Value = var.Value
End If

Set var1 = rng1.Find("Time: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var1 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 3)
pasterng.Value = var1.Value
End If

Set var2 = rng1.Find("Recording Duration: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var2 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 4)
pasterng.Value = var2.Value
End If

Set var3 = rng1.Find("Database: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var3 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 5)
pasterng.Value = var3.Value
End If

Set var4 = rng1.Find("Experiment: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var4 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 6)
pasterng.Value = var4.Value
End If

Set var5 = rng1.Find("Workspace: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var5 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 7)
pasterng.Value = var5.Value
End If

Set var6 = rng1.Find("Devices: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var6 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 8)
pasterng.Value = var6.Value
End If

Set var7 = rng1.Find("Program Description: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var7 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 9)
pasterng.Value = var7.Value
End If

Set var8 = rng1.Find("WP: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var8 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 10)
pasterng.Value = var8.Value
End If

Set var9 = rng1.Find("RP: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not var9 Is Nothing Then
lRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
lRows = lRow + 1
Set pasterng = ws2.Cells(lRows, 11)
pasterng.Value = var9.Value
End If

Set Comments = var9.Offset(0, 1)

Set Commentrng = ws1.Range(Comments, ws1.Cells(i, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
sizex = Commentrng.Columns.Count
sizexs = sizex + 11
Set Commentpaste = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(titlerows, 12), ws2.Cells(titlerows, sizexs))
Commentpaste.Value = Commentrng.Value

Next i
End Sub
```